# Ninject, ASP.NET and Custom Controls

Tags: asp.net, webforms, custom-controls, ninject, ioc-container

I'm currently using ASP.NET (standard, **not** MVC) and I'm using Ninject as my IOC container.

I'm already using it to inject dependencies into my pages, however, I was wondering if there was a way to inject dependencies into my custom controls?

If not, I'll get underway extending Ninject :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so I ended up extending Ninject and added two classes to Ninject.Framework.Web dll.

Heres the patch for anyone who's interested in adding it themselves:

```
Index: src/Framework/Web/Ninject.Framework.Web.csproj
===================================================================
--- src/Framework/Web/Ninject.Framework.Web.csproj  (revision 158)
+++ src/Framework/Web/Ninject.Framework.Web.csproj  (working copy)
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
   <PropertyGroup>
     <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
     <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
-    <ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
+    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
     <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
     <ProjectGuid>{C46075DB-A0FB-466B-BA76-C093227FA9C7}</ProjectGuid>
     <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
@@ -42,17 +42,24 @@
     <Reference Include="System.Core">
       <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
     </Reference>
+    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
+    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
     <Reference Include="System.Web" />
     <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
+    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
     <Compile Include="..\..\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs">
       <Link>Properties\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
     </Compile>
+    <Compile Include="WebControlBase.cs" />
     <Compile Include="NinjectHttpApplication.cs" />
     <Compile Include="HttpHandlerBase.cs">
     </Compile>
     <Compile Include="NinjectHttpModule.cs" />
+    <Compile Include="UserControlBase.cs">
+      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
+    </Compile>
     <Compile Include="WebServiceBase.cs">
       <SubType>Component</SubType>
     </Compile>
Index: src/Framework/Web/UserControlBase.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Framework/Web/UserControlBase.cs    (revision 0)
+++ src/Framework/Web/UserControlBase.cs    (revision 0)
@@ -0,0 +1,65 @@
+#region License
+//
+// Author: Nate Kohari <nkohari@gmail.com>
+// Copyright (c) 2007-2008, Enkari, Ltd.
+//
+// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
+// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
+// You may obtain a copy of the License at
+//
+//   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
+//
+// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
+// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
+// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
+// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
+// limitations under the License.
+//
+#endregion
+#region Using Directives
+using System;
+using Ninject.Core.Logging;
+using Ninject.Core;
+using System.Web.UI;
+#endregion
+
+namespace Ninject.Framework.Web
+{
+    /// <summary>
+    /// A <see cref="UserControl"/> that supports injection
+    /// </summary>
+    public class UserControlBase : UserControl
+    {
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+        private ILogger _logger;
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+        /// <summary>
+        /// Gets or sets the logger associated with the object.
+        /// </summary>
+        [Inject]
+        public ILogger Logger
+        {
+            get { return _logger; }
+            set { _logger = value; }
+        }
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+        /// <summary>
+        /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Web.UI.Control.Init"></see> event to initialize the page.
+        /// </summary>
+        /// <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"></see> that contains the event data.</param>
+        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
+        {
+            base.OnInit(e);
+            RequestActivation();  
+        }
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+        /// <summary>
+        /// Asks the kernel to inject this instance.
+        /// </summary>
+        protected virtual void RequestActivation()
+        {
+            KernelContainer.Inject(this);
+        }
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+    }
+}
Index: src/Framework/Web/WebControlBase.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Framework/Web/WebControlBase.cs (revision 0)
+++ src/Framework/Web/WebControlBase.cs (revision 0)
@@ -0,0 +1,65 @@
+#region License
+//
+// Author: Nate Kohari <nkohari@gmail.com>
+// Copyright (c) 2007-2008, Enkari, Ltd.
+//
+// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
+// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
+// You may obtain a copy of the License at
+//
+//   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
+//
+// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
+// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
+// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
+// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
+// limitations under the License.
+//
+#endregion
+#region Using Directives
+using System;
+using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
+using Ninject.Core.Logging;
+using Ninject.Core;
+#endregion
+
+namespace Ninject.Framework.Web
+{
+    /// <summary>
+    /// A <see cref="WebControl"/> that supports injection
+    /// </summary>
+    public class WebControlBase : WebControl
+    {
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+        ILogger _logger;
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+        /// <summary>
+        /// Gets or sets the logger associated with the object.
+        /// </summary>
+        [Inject]
+        public ILogger Logger
+        {
+            get { return _logger; }
+            set { _logger = value; }
+        }
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+        /// <summary>
+        /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Web.UI.Control.Init"></see> event to initialize the page.
+        /// </summary>
+        /// <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"></see> that contains the event data.</param>
+        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
+        {
+            base.OnInit(e);
+            RequestActivation();
+        }
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+        /// <summary>
+        /// Asks the kernel to inject this instance
+        /// </summary>
+        protected virtual void RequestActivation()
+        {
+            KernelContainer.Inject(this);
+        }
+        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
+    }
+}
```

Comment: Can you please at least post the raw XML instead of the formatted stuff you got fro IE?

Comment: This is an SVN patch for Ninject, which adds the ability to use Ninject with User Controls and Custom Controls in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by looping through all controls on the page, and injecting those who implement some interface.

The interface is empty:

```
public interface INinjectControl { }
```

I've added a loop to PageBase and MasterPageBase to inject all controls which implement this interface:

```
protected virtual void RequestActivation()
{
    KernelContainer.Inject( this );
    InjectControls(this.Controls);
}

private void InjectControls(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        if (control is INinjectControl)
            KernelContainer.Inject(control);
        this.InjectControls(control.Controls);
    }
}
```

There are some drawbacks:

- This only works for controls which are already on the page when
  OnInit fires. If you add a control later in the process, the loop has
  already run and the dependencies won't be injected.
- This calls CreateChildControls() on some controls, because you request the Controls collection. This can lead to problems because this method is now called far earlier in the lifecycle.
- It loops through all controls, so it is not very efficient.